# Binding to DataGridTemplateColumn in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datacontext, datagridtemplatecolumn

I am customizing WPF DataGrid in a generic way. consider that I have defined an enum of Creatures like this:

```
public enum CreatureType
{
    Human,
    Animal,
    Insect,
    Virus
}
```

then I have an attached property of the above type so it can be attached to any control I want, that called **CreatureTypeProeprty**. then I want to attach this property to **DataGridTemplateColumn** and I want to access this inside the Template. for example consider the following reproducible code of my problem:

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn local:CreatureTypeProeprty.Value = "Human" Width="*">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(local:CreatureTypeProeprty.Value), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridTemplateColumn }}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

This doesn't work and I know why because **DataGrid column is not part of the visual tree.** but I can't find any way to solve this issue. I also tried [This](https://thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/) but this solution can not be used in a generic way and ends up in a very dirty solution! I'm looking for a more sophisticated and clean way. I also tried using the name for the column and specifying **ElementName** it works but also this can not be used when there is multiple columns and I have to repeat codes every time.

Comment: I added some code. It's probably more complicated than you need but maybe your real case is more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datagrid column is more a conceptual thing.  It's not so much not in the visual tree as not there at all.

There is no spoon.

One way to do this sort of thing would be to use a list and index it. In your window viewmode

```
public list<CreatureType> Creatures {get;set;}
```

Obviously, load that up with CreatureTypes in the same order as your columns.

You can then reference using something like

```
  Text="{Binding DataContext.Creatures[4]} 
, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
  AncestorType=Datagrid}}
```

Unfortunately, you need a fixed number for indexing.

You could perhaps dynamically build your columns and add them to the datagrid.

I would do that by defining a string template and substituting values, then using xamlreader.parse() to build a datagrid column which you add to your datagrid.

In my sample I have a col.txt file. This is a sort of template for my datagrid columns.

It is pretty much a piece of datagrid column markup.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="xxMMMxx" TextAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Units" Margin="2,0,2,0" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Value" Margin="2,0,2,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" />
    </Grid>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MonthTotals[xxNumxx].Products}" Margin="2,0,2,0" TextAlignment="Right"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MonthTotals[xxNumxx].Total}"    Margin="2,0,2,0" TextAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

It's showing totals for months so obviously 12 months and my array here is monthtotals[12].
Obviously, this is a different thing and illustrating the approach.

I also have a dg.txt file which is of course something rather similar for my datagrid. But that'd be repetitive.

And I have some code substitutes strings, parses the result and appends a built column:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the datagrid shell
        XElement xdg = GetXElement(@"pack://application:,,,/dg.txt");  
        XElement cols = xdg.Descendants().First();     // Column list
        // Get the column template
        XElement col = GetXElement(@"pack://application:,,,/col.txt");  

        DateTime mnth = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6);

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            DateTime dat = mnth.AddMonths(i);
            XElement el = new XElement(col);
            // Month in mmm format in header
            var mnthEl = el.Descendants("TextBlock")
                        .Single(x => x.Attribute("Text").Value.ToString() == "xxMMMxx");
            mnthEl.SetAttributeValue("Text", dat.ToString("MMM"));

            string monthNo = dat.AddMonths(-1).Month.ToString();
            // Month as index for the product
            var prodEl = el.Descendants("TextBlock")
                        .Single(x => x.Attribute("Text").Value == "{Binding MonthTotals[xxNumxx].Products}");
            prodEl.SetAttributeValue("Text",
                "{Binding MonthTotals[" + monthNo + "].Products}");
            // Month as index for the total
            var prodTot = el.Descendants("TextBlock")
                        .Single(x => x.Attribute("Text").Value == "{Binding MonthTotals[xxNumxx].Total}");
            prodTot.SetAttributeValue("Text",
                "{Binding MonthTotals[" + monthNo + "].Total}");
            cols.Add(el);
        }

        string dgString = xdg.ToString();
        ParserContext context = new ParserContext();
        context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation");
        context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");
        DataGrid dg = (DataGrid)XamlReader.Parse(dgString, context);
        Root.Children.Add(dg);
    }
    private XElement GetXElement(string uri)
    {
        XDocument xmlDoc = new XDocument();
        var xmltxt = Application.GetContentStream(new Uri(uri));
        string elfull = new StreamReader(xmltxt.Stream).ReadToEnd();
        xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(elfull);
        return xmlDoc.Root;
    }
```

Might be more complicated than you need but maybe it'll help someone else down the line.

BTW

I suggest an "unknown" or "none" as the first in any enum. This is standard practice in my experience so you can differentiate between a set and unset value.

Q1 How common is this?

Not very. It solves problems I would describe as "awkward" bindings and can simplify UI logic in templating.

Or a sort of super auto generator for columns.

A similar approach can be very useful for user configurable UI or dynamic UI.

Imagine a dynamic UI where the user is working with xml and xml defines the UI.  Variable stats or variable points calculation for a tabletop wargaming points calculator.

Or where the user picks the columns they want and how to display them.  That can be built as strings and saved to their roaming profile. Loaded from there using xamlreader.load which gives you your entire datagrid definition.

q2
That's what the sample does.

dg.txt looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<DataGrid
          ItemsSource="{Binding SalesMen}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          Grid.Column="1"
          CanUserAddRows="False"
          IsReadOnly="False"
    Name="dg">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FullName}"  Header="Name"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This line gets Columns

```
 XElement cols = xdg.Descendants().First();     // Column list
```

And this line append each column

```
 cols.Add(el);
```

It is so there are Xelement nodes you can find that the file is manipulated as xml rather than just as a string.

Comment: Thank you for your solution but my case is a more complicated scenario than provided example. I only want the way to workaround this issue so i can apply it other properties as well. BTW, would you mind writing a complete example of the case you said with parse() method? and about the final advice yes i agree with you i just write an example sorry about not being complete ;)

Comment: Thank you. I will read it and maybe ask you questions if you don't mind :)

Comment: Sure, feel free. Questions is what SO's about. :^)  Mostly.

Comment: The first question is if you want to grade this solution what would be the grade? I mean is this type of solution (XElement, reading stream, and ...) widely used, or is it just a workaround for this specific problem because of its nature?

Comment: The next is if I do not have DataGrid text file how can I convert ColumnTemplate from Text to actual column and add it to the DataGrid columns list?

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort and knowledge sharing I really do appreciate it. at the end of the day although it seems a little awkward and maybe a crazy way of UI definition but today I learned a tool that as you said can give us a very good ability to define more complex and dynamic UI. I hope you the best wishes man :))